# Databind between one textbox and an ObservableCollection of child objects

Tags: wpf, c#-4.0, data-binding, observablecollection, children

I've the following situation:

```
class A { myCollection = new ObservableCollection<B>(); 
....
 myCollection.Add(new B1());
 myCollection.Add(new B2());
....
for each (B b in myCollection)
   b.DoWork();

}
```

where B is an abstract class with a set of specialized subclasses (let's say B1, B2...).
B has the "State" property, and the DoWork method that is overridden by his subclasses.
The state property is changed differently in each specialized DoWork.

```
  abstract class B { 
        string _state = null;
        public string State
        {
            get
            {
                return _state;
            }
            set
            {
                _state = value;
                OnPropertyChanged( "State" );
            }

        public bool DoWork();
   }

 class B1:B { 
    override public bool DoWork()
            {
                State = "Press button XXXX to do something";
                .....
                return true;
            }
    }

class B2:B { 
        override public bool DoWork()
                {
                    State = "Press button YYYY to do something else";
                    ....
                    return true;
                }
        }
```

In my xaml file datacontext is A, and I dont't know how to set Binding:

```
<Window.DataContext>
    <!-- Declaratively create an instance of A-->
    <VW:A />
</Window.DataContext>
....
<TextBox Text="{Binding Path=????State????}" />
```

I want to change the TextBox text with databinding when calling

```
for each (B b in myCollection)
       b.DoWork();
```

I've tryed several binding istructions but it doesn't works....

***SOLUTION THANKS TO SHERIGAN:***

The SHERIGAN solution is good if you wanto to show all property of all object in the collection **togheter**, BUT

What i was actually trying to achive was to have a collection of object that all updates the **same** visual component. Objects in collection represents states, so there is always only one active.
so what i did is edit class A:

```
class A { myCollection = new ObservableCollection<B>(); 
....
 private B temp;
 myCollection.Add(new B1());
 myCollection.Add(new B2());
....
for each (B b in myCollection) {
   temp = b
   temp.DoWork();
}

public B TEMP
    {
        get
        {
            return temp;
        }

        set
        {
            temp = value;
            OnPropertyChanged( "TEMP" );
        }
    }
```

and in xaml

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Path=TEMP.State}"/>

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, you'll need a `public` collection property in class `A` and it will also need to implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface. Then you'd need to `Bind` that collection property to a collection control:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding CollectionProperty}">
    ...
</ListBox>
```

Then you can set what each item should look like in the `ItemTemplate`:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding CollectionProperty}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type YourXmlNamespace:B}">
            <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=State}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

I have a feeling that using base classes in your XAML will not work, but I could be wrong. You might have to set the `DataType` property to either `B1` or `B2` instead. This *may* or *may not* work for an instance of `A`... I can't test this at the moment.

---

UPDATE >>>

It sounds like you have an empty item in your collection that is having an `ItemTemplate` (the `TextBox`) generated for it. However, you don't actually *have* to use a collection control to display an item from a collection... if you just want to display one item, you should be able to use the indexer `Binding.Path` syntax:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding CollectionProperty[0].State}" />
```

Comment: <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type YourXmlNamespace:B}"> gives compile errors, so i used <DataTemplate DataType="this:B">, but binding still doesn't work.

Comment: What errors did you get? Hopefully you understand about [adding XML Namespaces](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms747086.aspx) and that you need to add one for the `YourXmlNamespace` prefix that I used in my example.

Comment: Ok i got it work defining  `xmlns:custom="clr-namespace:mynamespace.BSubNamespace"` and  `<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type custom:B}">`. It also works without declaring xmlns:custom and using `<DataTemplate DataType="this:B">`. The core concept is that i first need to bind the collection to get a bind to a property inside the objects contained in the collection.

Comment: But now i have a visual issue: seems that putting textbox inside a listbox adds 1 more textbox below the correct one... any ideas?

Comment: I got it, listbox automatically create a textbox for every object in mycollection. I post my final solution in open post. Anyway can you explain what is the difference between using `<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type custom:B}">` and `<DataTemplate DataType="this:B">`?

Comment: I have to be honest, I've never seen anybody using `this` as a namespace prefix before. If you haven't declared it as a namespace, then I can only imagine that in `<DataTemplate DataType="this:B">`, `this` refers to the class that it is declared in, or the namespace of that class to be more specific, so if that namespace is `BSubNamespace`, then there is no *real* difference between using that or the `custom` prefix. However, it is good practice to use the name of the actual namespace, just in case you ever want to use the control(s) from that namespace externally.